# Filter function from coefficients in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, filtering, math.net

Is there a function (possibly within [Math.Net](https://filtering.mathdotnet.com/)) that takes an array of numerator and denominator coefficients of a digital filter and uses that to filter an input array?

Something like MATLAB's [filter()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) function or Python's [scipy.signal.lfilter()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) would be awesome.

Comment: Something like https://filtering.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Filtering.IIR/OnlineIirFilter.htm ?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for pointing it out. :)